# "Cannot update SLA process that is in use" when deploying an SLA process, but it is not in use

Tags: change-set, entitlements, entitlement-process

Two organizations have the same entitlement process. One of them is outdated and I created a change set to update it. When deploying to the outdated org, I get this message.

When we try to delete an entitlement process that is in use by an Entitlement or a Case record, we get the error message that says that it cannot be deleted. In this situation, however, there are no Entitlement records that reference the process, and the cases that used to reference them were all deleted (it is a sandbox, so no problem with this).

I tried to create a new version for this process (versioning is enabled on both orgs), but I get the same message for the "v2" process.

Is there a way to deploy a change set containing an updated SLA process?

Comment: I think if you deploy the updated SLA process in the target org, you need to create a new version after actionation. Pls check

Comment: No, it does not work. I tried to create a new version before deploying the change set and I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jmRCQAY) without a fix. You have to create the new version in the intended org.